# Animation on top of static plot on plotly

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I am new to plotly on python.
I tried to create a dynamic plot on top of static plot. I have a dataframe df as follow:

```
Date      |    Time    | Easting   | Northing  | Truck ID
==========================================================
30/01/2019| 4:36:21 AM | 3147564   | 60394857  |  TR555
...
```

consider I have only 1 truck for now. I want to animate the movement of the truck. What I did is:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.scatter(df, x="Easting", y="Northing", animation_frame="Time", animation_group="TruckID",
           color="TruckID",
           log_x=True, size_max=100, range_x=[min(df['Easting'])-100,max(df['Easting'])+100],
           range_y=[min(df['Northing'])-100,max(df['Northing'])+100])
```

This will animate the movement of truck in which a scatter will move based on the easting and northing. However, I want to plot static line to show the "road"

I tried adding line :

```
px.line(df['Easting'], df['Northing']).show()
```

But it will only display the static line chart without the scatter animation.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is fig.add_trace

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).